# How to get the Sum of column in Android using SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, sum, multiple-columns

I have looked at several other related questions that have been asked, but can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I'm trying to get the total amount (as a double) of a column in my database so that I can display a running total of tips that I've made. I stumbled upon the code that I need to do the calculation, which is:

```
public int getTotal(){
    int sum = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(KEY_DELIVERY_TOTAL) FROM TABLE_CONTACTS ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        sum = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I put this method in my Handler class, which I'm not sure is the correct place to put it, but makes the most sense to me. I have my Adapter class as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, null);

    TextView name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    TextView contact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
    TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressConverted);
    TextView orderTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderTotalConverted);
    TextView amountReceived = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountReceivedConverted);
    TextView tip = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipConverted);
    TextView mileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mileageConverted);
    TextView grandTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grandTotalConverted);
    Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    PhoneBook list = contactList.get(position);

    name.setText(list.getName());
    contact.setText(list.getPhoneNumber());
    address.setText(list.getAddress());
    orderTotal.setText(list.getOrderTotal());
    amountReceived.setText(list.getAmountReceived());
    tip.setText(list.getTip());
    mileage.setText(list.getMileage());
    grandTotal.setText(list.getGrandTotal());
    delete.setOnClickListener(new ListItemClickListener(position, list));


    TextView deliveryNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliveryNum);
    deliveryNumber.setText("Delivery #" + (position + 1));

    return convertView;
}
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to set the column sum as a string to use in a textView so that I can display it in a listView? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: orderTotal.setText(""+list.getOrderTotal());

Comment: Will that display a running total for the orderTotal column? I'm sorry, I should've been more specific in my question. I am trying to get the running total of my "Grand Total" column. So for delivering pizzas, the grand total is the total made from tip and mileage. Each time a new entry is saved to the database, my goal is to add the grand total with the previous grand total. So if I made 2.50 on the first one, and 4.00 on the second, the 2nd listView would say 6.50.

Comment: so it should be     grandTotal.setText("" + list.getGrandTotal());

Comment: For some reason, it's just staying the same. Each entry into the database just displays the grand Total for that entry and is not a running total. If I create a textView called "runningTotal" and did something like TextView runningTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);
        runningTotal.setText("" + list.getGrandTotal());  This would be perfect if it would be a running total of all the previous grandTotals combined.

Comment: Not sure if i clearly understand your goal, since the first method you specified is not used in the adapter. Did I understand right, that your methods `getOrderTotal` and `getGrandTotal` work the same way (calculate the sum of a particular column and return it) or they use the method `getTotal` within them? If so, could you provide the snippet with these methods body at well? Is the problem around these methods or anywhere else?

Comment: getOrderTotal gets the total price of the transaction. Which is the price the pizza cost. Anything extra the customer pays is the driver's tip. And with mileage (gas reimbursement for driving their own vehicle) added in, there is a "grandTotal" the driver made on the delivery. All of this is saved in one row in my database for each delivery. I'm trying to get the sum of the grandTotal column. So 4 deliveries = 4 entries in the grandTotal column. If all 4 tip 5.00 with mileage, the total should be 20.00.

Comment: Each delivery is saved to the database and displayed in a listView. So the first total would say 5.00, the second 10.00, third 15.00, and the 4th 20.00. My goal is to create a textview field that displays the running total of the sum of the grandTotal column.